# Django model object is deleted when I update the model object that has as foreign key

Tags: python, django

I have this two models in my models.py archive:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description_issue = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("publication date", default=timezone.now)

class PossibleSolution(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description_solution = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    final = models.BooleanField()
    sol_date = models.DateTimeField("solution date", default=timezone.now)
    tickets = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, blank=True, null=True)
```

Example: I have a Ticket, with a name, description and the publication date, and then I create a PossibleSolution, and in the form from which I create the PossibleSolution, I choose the related ticket.

Then, in another form, I update the original Ticket, changing it's name, and then I lose the PossibleSolution I created.

What can be happening here?

EDIT: This is the from from where I edit the Ticket

```
class TicketForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(TicketForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['pub_date'].widget = widgets.AdminSplitDateTime()
            self.fields['closing_date'].widget = widgets.AdminSplitDateTime()
            self.fields['issuer'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

        model = Ticket
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {
            'name': _('Nombre'),
            'description_issue': _('Descripción'),
            'pub_date': _('Fecha de creacion'),
            'closing_date': _('Fecha de cierre'),
            'priority': _('Prioridad'),
            'issuer': _('Creado por'),
            'category': _('Categoría')
        }
        widgets = {
            'pub_date': DateTimeWidget(attrs={'id': "pub_date"}, usel10n=True, bootstrap_version=3),
            'closing_date': DateTimeWidget(attrs={'id': "closing_date"}, usel10n=True, bootstrap_version=3),
        }
```

And this is the view where I have the POST

```
def ticket(request, id_ticket):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TicketForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            messages.success(request, 'ticket-saved')
            if id_ticket and int(id_ticket) > 0:
                # I have this because I don't know how to really modify
                Ticket.objects.get(id=id_ticket).delete()
            return redirect('index')
```

Comment: Please do provide the forms..

Comment: show what are you trying to update, the view and the form

Comment: Updating `Ticket` can not delete the related objects unless you explicitely ask for it somewhere. Either you're creating a new ticket instead of updating an existing one or you do have some code (your own code, not django's) that delete the solutions.

Comment: I think I saw the flaw, old code, but I can't know how to rreally modify then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the line which performs the delete query,

```
def ticket(request, id_ticket):
    ticket = Ticket.objects.get(id=id_ticket)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TicketForm(request.POST, instance=ticket)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            messages.success(request, 'ticket-saved')
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = TicketForm(instance=ticket)
    return render(request, 'template_name', {'form':form})
```

Comment: But then, is not modifying the ticket, is saving another one, right?

Comment: Is still deleting it.

Comment: You need to remove the line with `delete()`, otherwise it would still delete the ticket. Double check and try again friend.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I forgot one line, I deleted it and now it's working. Thanks!